# Using remote XServer

Tags: linux, xorg, tcp, remote-control

I recall seeing a tutorial on setting up Xorg to be a vnc replacement without installing anything, but I cannot find it. I was hoping someone here could help out. Scenario:

Machine A

- no monitor
- xclient connects to Machine B via TCP/IP on boot

Machine B

- has monitor(s)
- xserver listens for Machine A via TCP/IP on boot

How can I accomplish this without installing extra software from repositories (apt/yum/etc.)?

**EDIT:**

To clarify things, I have 2 scenarios for Machine A:

Scenario 1:

- Distro: Kali image for Raspberry Pi
- Packages: Stock
- Hardware: Accessible

Scenario 2:

- Distro: Ubuntu Server 14.04
- Packages: `kde-full` package installed
- Hardware: ***Not*** accessible

As a side note I do ***not*** want SSH X-forwarding. I want it to show as if Machine A is directly connected to Machine B's monitors.

Comment: What, exactly, are you trying to accomplish?  are you trying to get an Xsession on machine A?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and most secure way is to connect via `ssh` from Machine B to Machine A and start the application from inside the `ssh` session:

```
ssh -X machine_a.example.com some_application
```

`X11Forwarding` has to be enabled on the SSH-Server, i.e. Machine A. If you want not only a single application (say minesweeper) but the complete environment, replace `some_application` with the start program of that environment.

EDIT: Looks like you want to use Machine B as a Xterminal (a piece of hardware, not to be confused with `xterm`) for Machine A. The X11 way to do this is via remote X login (see the other answer). However, this is as bad as using `telnet` security-wise. An alternative is to start an X server on Machine B, but only an X server, nothing else (no windowmanager etc.). Start an SSH connection as described above. Your Machine A windowmanager will run "full screen" without decorations from your local windowmanager (because there is none), so it looks as if you have an Xterminal.

Answer (score 1):

You might be thinking of xdmcp; remote GUI login via either XDM ar GDM.

Part of your requirement is that the solution needs no new software to be installed, but you give no details about the systems you are running, so it's difficult to propose a definitive solution. But generally speaking: enable `xdmcp` in your login manager config.

I have never used GDM to do this, but with XDM, you can specify which host on your network you want to log into. Its desktop appears on your monitor one logged in successfully.

Firewalls might be an issue, so remember to open a port for xdmcp traffic.

We use this method at work, internally. The data is not encrypted in any way, so it's unlike VNC or SSH in that way.

Comment: I added clarification on the systems. One of the systems is internally networked, but the other is behind strict firewalls that is on a whitelist basis and is tunneled through a secure VPN for encryption. _P.S.: I could have swore the tut didn't use a login manager._

Comment: I'm not sure what you looked at, but here's another guess: FreeNX. Its popular implementation, as far as I have ever heard, is NoMachine http://nomachine.com but obviously that would require additional installation.